# How To Display Selected Terms For Custom Taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, include

This may be a syntax problem but if so I can't see the problem.

I want to select specific terms of a custom taxonomy and display their names. I'm having a problem with the selection process in the following code.

```
$taxonomy = 'chapters';
echo("Test Term Display ");
$args1=array(
    'include'=> array(74,76
        )
    );
$chaptertitles=get_terms( 'chapters', $args1 );
$count1 = count($chaptertitles);
echo($count1);
 if ( $count1 > 0 ){
   echo "<ul>";
      foreach ( $chaptertitles as $chaptertitle ) {
   echo "<li> Chapter Title:" . $chaptertitle->name . "</li>";

  }
 echo "</ul>";
}
```

This returns zero for $count1.

However, if I remove the arguements so that the default conditions apply then I get all the terms returned.

This suggests that my syntax is incorrect for $args1 but I can't see any errors.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to get this working.

Thx

Comment: is it possible that those terms are empty?

Comment: Thx. Yes that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is that by default terms having no posts are not displayed. This can be changed by adding "hide_empty"=>0 to the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to find your solution.

1. print the result of get_terms without arguments

   ```
   $chaptertitles=get_terms( 'chapters');      
   print_r($chaptertitles);
   ```
2. Check in above result can you get the item id 74 & 76.
3. I think you might not get the the item id 74 & 76 that's why you get the     zero for $count1.
4. Include the item which you may get in `$chaptertitles`.

Comment: Thx. As noted in my answer the solution is simply to turn off suppression of terms that don't have posts.